# Shape error when reading tfrecords with tf.data.TFRecordDataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape, tfrecord

I've created a tfrecords file with my own images, and when I try to read it using tf.data.TFRecordDataset, a shape error comes:
[image]
I created the tfrecords with codes:

```
def _int64_feature(value):
return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def _bytes_feature(value):
return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def img_to_tfrecord(data_path):
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('test_imgs/test.tfrecords')

file = open('test_imgs/test.txt')
for line in file.readlines():
    img_name = line.split(' ')[0]
    label = int(line.split(' ')[1])
    img_path = data_path + '/test_imgs/' + img_name

    img = Image.open(img_path)
    img = img.resize((224, 224))
    img_bytes = img.tobytes()

    feature={'train_img': _bytes_feature(img_bytes),
             'train_label': _int64_feature(label)}
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()
```

And read it with codes:

```
def parser(record):
parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, {'train_img': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
                                          'train_label': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64)})

image = tf.decode_raw(parsed['train_img'], tf.uint8)
image = tf.reshape(image, [224, 224, 3])
label = tf.cast(parsed['train_label'], tf.int32)

return image, label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('test_imgs/test.tfrecords')
    dataset = dataset.map(parser)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=6).batch(4).repeat(2)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    img, label = iterator.get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
       a,b=sess.run([img, label])
       print(a.shape)
```

Since 150528=224*224*3, how does 200704 comes from？ I've read lots of tutorials but I still can't solve this problem. I've already paid attention to the parsing type of the code: image = tf.decode_raw(parsed['train_img'], tf.uint8). Anyone could help me, I'm about to break down.
The images using to create the tfrecords are like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it. My god. It's about the pictures themselves. The bit depth of one of the pictures is 32. Then its shape would be (224,224,4).

[image]